# javascript getOwnPropertyNames method

Tags: javascript

why dont **Object.getOwnPropertyNames()** not return call and apply method of the function?

```
 function arr(){};

 Object.getOwnPropertyNames(arr);//output:arguments,length,prototype,caller only
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because those properties are on the `Function` prototype, not on the function itself.  Thats actually the whole point of the method, to filter out properties that are on the prototype and not on the object itself.